# Disable WebSecurity for pre-prod environments Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I am trying to use authentication for our swagger on production. That was going great, when i try to access the swagger it requires password and username. I want this functionality only for production env. Not sure how to disable it for different profiles/environments. I tried with if-else based on .yml property but that caused other problems. POST and UPDATE methods started to return 403 Forbidden. Here is sample code:

```
   @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("!test")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Value("${server.environment}")
    private String environment;

    @Value("${swagger.user}")
    private String swaggerUser;

    @Value("${swagger.password}")
    private String swaggerPass;




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if("stage".equals(environment) || "prod".equals(environment)){
            LOGGER.info("Environment: " + environment + " swagger authentication is on");
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        } else {
            http.csrf().disable();
            LOGGER.info("Environment: " + environment + " swagger authentication is off");
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(swaggerUser).password("{noop}" + swaggerPass).roles("USER");
    }
```

I have tried to disable the whole WebSecurityConfig bean but that didn work because the dependency is there, and now everytime it asks for Login.

Tried this , didnt work:

```
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        }
```

Comment: Please share the relevant logs and the URL you are making a request along with the profiles you have and the active profiles

Comment: how about having your pre-prod endpoints start at /preprod and permitAll for everything comes after like /preprod/**? you can keep the web security config as well., just add new one for preprod endpoints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended approach is to create another class for production and pre-release environments instead of using if-else. You may need to permit the other endpoints using `permitAll()` or need to add authority based methods such as `hasRole()`. Also make sure you don't have any security annotation at the controller such as `@PreAuthorized, @Secured` etc.

**Recommended Approach:**

Security configurations for prod or staging environment

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("prod")
public class WebSecurityProductionConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityProductionConfig.class);

    @Value("${server.environment}")
    private String environment;

    @Value("${swagger.user}")
    private String swaggerUser;

    @Value("${swagger.password}")
    private String swaggerPass;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Environment: " + environment + " swagger authentication is on");

        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("**/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(swaggerUser).password("{noop}" + swaggerPass).roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Security configurations for dev and another environment

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("!prod")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Security configuration for the non prod env is loaded");
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/**").permitAll();
    }

}
```

---

**If-Else Approach**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("!test")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Value("${server.environment}")
    private String environment;

    @Value("${swagger.user}")
    private String swaggerUser;

    @Value("${swagger.password}")
    private String swaggerPass;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        
        if ("stage".equals(environment) || "prod".equals(environment)) {
            LOGGER.info("Environment: " + environment + " swagger authentication is on");
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").authenticated();
        } else {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/**").permitAll();
            LOGGER.info("Environment: " + environment + " swagger authentication is off");
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(swaggerUser).password("{noop}" + swaggerPass).roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add another implementation of `WebSecurityConfig` which will allow free access to your swagger, and use `@ConditionalOnProperty` to determine which implementation should be used based on a property from your application.yml.

Comment: I could use different WebSecurityConfig but not sure how to allow access for all endpoints. If i use the `http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();` method it doesnt do anything. Still got 403 from POSTs and UPDATEs

Answer (score 0):

Your approach from the beginning seems good,

1. You create a profile called "test" with configuration like this:
   `application-test.properties`
   spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
2. Then add test profile on WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter by adding the @Profile("!test") same as what I see you did
3. Enjoin with test profile without security configuration by active test profile

`java --spring.profiles.active=test -jar yourapp.jar`

or

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.profiles.active=test`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to config security for prod environment, you only need to implement WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for prod environment.

```
    @Profile("prod")
    @Configuration
    public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.csrf().disable()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .httpBasic();
        }
    }
```

For more information please this blog: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-disable-profile